# SinglePageApplication 404-Error

Tags: asp.net, singlepage, upshot

I am trying to programm a SPA using Upshot.js when i came to a problem.

```
upshot.metadata(@(Html.Metadata<...>()));
```

Error: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Metadata'

I solved this by adding the following line:

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Http.Data.Helpers" />
```

in the web.config file.

but now there is a 404 error.
It does not find the Index.cshtml file.

Before i added the "upshot.metadat...." line it worked well.
So i can't understand where the problem is.